# Javascript postMessage, how long should I wait?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, message

I'm sending a message from an iframe like this just before redirecting:

```
window.parent.postMessage('hide', '*');
console.log("message sent");

window.location = "url";
```

I'm not sure if `postMessage` is async or if it could be any problem to leave that page using window.location that may cause the message not to reach destination.

I think the possible answers are 1 of these 3:

1. No problem at all, message gets sent no matter what happens to that page after.
2. I should delay that `window.location` with setTimeout.
3. I should listen to a response to be sure it has being sent.

Comment: what have you observed in your testing? - by the way, it **is** asynchronous

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter (1), but I would like to be sure that this is the expected behaviour in every browser and situation

Comment: well, the only 100% sure way, and future proof for any browser that supports postMessage, would be (3) - nothing in the spec that I can see - https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/comms.html#dom-window-postmessage

Comment: reading the above spec, the function "returns" at step 8, but at step 10/11, there's the implication that the Window object of the sender is being used - so, theoretically in my mind there's nothing in the spec to guarantee the message should be sent